What is the advantage of x-ray spectroscopy to lower-energy spectroscopy?
There are of course many types of x-ray spectroscopy, so let us be specific and focus on x-ray absorption spectroscopy. People excite a core electron to study the outer eletrons.
But the energy scale of the outer electrons, which are responsible for most physical and chemical properties of the material, is much lower than that of x-rays.
Why not study the outer electrons simply with visible light?

What information are you thinking that you will be obtaining with your suggestion?

For one, both the penetration depth of the pump x-ray and the escape depth of the decay x-ray are much longer than normal visible extinction depths, so you get signal from much more material.
